# Private Route components does not infer types from hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

so in my React App i use Private Routes in my routing component:

```
  const PrivateRoute = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const { session } = useAuth();

  return !session ? <Navigate to={"/"} /> : children;
};
```

UseAuth hook:

```
export const useAuth = () => {
  const session = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (!session) {
      return { session: null, currentUser: null };
    }

  const currentUser = session.user;
  return { session, currentUser };
};
```

Here is example of Dashboard component nested in Private Route:

```
 <Route
      path="/dashboard"
      element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <Dashboard />
        </PrivateRoute>
      }
    />
```

Now in my Dashboard Component im getting error `'currentUser' is possibly 'null'`:

```
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  const { data: user_assignments } = useGetUserAssignments(currentUser.id);
```

**Why in my private routes components i'm receiving that `'currentUser' is possibly 'null'.ts(18047)`when it clearly only renders components when session is not null?**

Comment: *Where* in `PrivateRoute` is any `currentUser` variable/value even referenced? Is this a complete [mcve] of the code you are working with? Are you sure you have the error correct? Can you [edit] to share the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dashboard` component isn't aware that it is being conditionally rendered. Typescript can only infer the provided Context value/type returned from the `useAuth` hook, which includes `currentUser` being null.

You can use the Optional Chaining Operator (`?.`) or a null-check/guard-clause to check if `currentUser` exists, and provide a valid fallback value to the `useGetUserAssignments` hook.

```js
const { currentUser } = useAuth();

const { data: user_assignments } = useGetUserAssignments(currentUser?.id ?? "");
```

```js
const { currentUser } = useAuth();

const { data: user_assignments } = useGetUserAssignments(
  (currentUser && currentUser.id) ?? ""
);
```

Or if you feel reasonably confident that it's the case that `currentUser` can ***never*** be null when `Dashboard` is rendered you can assert this with the [Non-null Assertion Operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (`!`).

```js
const { currentUser } = useAuth();

const { data: user_assignments } = useGetUserAssignments(currentUser!.id);
```

### Just FYI

A more conventional `PrivateRoute` implementation renders an `Outlet` instead of a `children` prop. This allows wrapping and protecting more than one route/component at-a-time.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const { session } = useAuth();

  return session ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

```
<Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
  <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
  {/* other protected routes */}
</Route>
```